# How do I align text in a excel cell with javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, text-alignment

I am developing an Excell add-in. Using a GUI I am passing two variables to a function. X being the value of the input from the GUI and the other is a location pointer to set the cell. If the value of the input is 7, I want to set the cell horizontal alignment to left. I have tried all kinds of different syntax that I found online but none work, nor do they give an error.

I have tried:

```
if (x == 7) { range.horizontalAlignment = "left" }
if (x == 7) { range.Excel.horizontalAlignment = "left" }
if (x == 7) { range.format.horizontalAlignment = "left" }
if (x == 7) { range.horizontalAlignment = Excel.horizontalAlignment = "left" }
```

and some others I don't remember.

```
    function getValue(x, y) {
        Excel.run(function (context) {
            var text = document.getElementById(x).value;
            var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
            var range;
            if (y == 1) { range = sheet.getRange("F5") };
            if (y == 2) {
                range = sheet.getRange("F9");
                if (x == 7) { range.horizontalAlignment = "left" } // Problem line, I think                    
            };
            range.values = (text); // Put into cell 'range'
            return context.sync()
        });
}
```